# npm install -g @angular/cli not executing

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[image]

I've tried executing the command `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` and `npm install -g @angular/cli`. Both of them are giving this error.

Comment: Which version of node are you using ?

Comment: You have node installed on your system?

Comment: Yes. Node is installed

Answer (score 0):

i think it's related to compatibility between node and npm versions, You can try [NVM for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)
and then you can use it to install a specific node version and it will install the compatible npm version with it

```
nvm install 12.8.1
```

you can install multiple versions of node if you want and switch between them

```
nvm list
```

[image]

for example you can switch to use 8.11.3 like this:

```
nvm use 8.11.3
```

imagine that i want to install node 13.3 with **nvm install 13.3**, nvm will install **npm 6.13.1** with it

[image]

Please have a look a lon on the list of releases her https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score 0):

please check with your internet connectivity, proxy or npm registry. It look like it is not able to reach to npm repo to bring the angular cli